# Opencvsharp4.windows The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Mat' threw an exception.This error was received after the setup file created

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv, image-processing, dll

I am developing a windows form. I added from manage  package in visual studio. Program is working in locale but If I load app to different computer, I get this error. In my estimation, dll error. 
I've been dealing with this error for weeks..How can I solve this problem. Thank you in advance for your contributions

Comment: You are using [OpenCVSharp4][1]  - Please have a look here https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/605 , same issue

Comment: I have two ideas, maybe your target platform is different, e.g. x64 .dll and you build your project for Any CPU, and you should also make sure that the .dll is included in the debug / release folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using a WinForms app with OpenCvSharp. I ran into this issue when I pulled down my feature branch which added `OpenCvSharp4` and `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win` onto a different computer. When the packages properly build, they should generate a directory called `dll` in your `bin` directory for your target platform. For some reason, that `dll` directory wasn't being generated.

I was able to fix the issue by simply uninstalling the NuGet packages, reinstalling them, then rebuilding.